# How many times a day will an AWS budget monitor the cost incurred by an account?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Once a budget is setup in AWS, how often will it monitor the cost incurred by the account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a statement straight out of the AWS documentation:

"AWS Budgets information is updated up to three times a day. Budgets track your unblended costs, subscriptions, refunds, and RIs."

Comment: Judging from the documentation, it looks like the number of times that AWS monitors the cost incurred isn't exactly a fixed value. Can someone elaborate this statement?

Answer (score 0):

Estimate cost updated every 6 hours.

Check **Total Estimated Charge** metric by following the [Creating an Alarm](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/monitor_estimated_charges_with_cloudwatch.html#creating_billing_alarm_with_wizard) tutorial. You will see data updated every 6 hours.

Comment: I wasn't actually referring to the CloudWatch alarms. I was referring to the AWS Budgets which allow you to specify a limit w.r.t to the cost that you incur.

Comment: I think logic is the same. To send you budget alarm, AWS needs to populate the total Charge